# How to draw heart rate monitor on Android

Tags: android, api, real-time, graphic, pulse

I'm trying to develop an Android app that shows a Heart Rate Monitor (commonly known as pulse) receiving data in real time from an smartband through Bluetooth. Do any of you know about some easy API to draw this kind of graphic in Android?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just last week Robinhood released Spark, a library that makes charting sparklines very easy.

[Introducing Spark](https://medium.com/robinhood-engineering/introducing-spark-dc17269b83f6#.h5k7rtdrx)